(How) can I determine the point of tangency of $k\cdot x$ and $\sin{x}$?
Is it possible to determine the exact coordinates of the point of tangency of a line through the origin $k\cdot x$ and $\sin{x}$, with a $k$ chosen so there exists a unique point of tangency? The situation is shown in the Geogebra image below.


Try to observe the graph of function $h(x)= \sin {x} - k\cdot x$

@z100 You mean I do $h'(x)=\cos{x}-k$ and set that to zero? I'm just having trouble because I know neither $x$ nor the correct $k$.

Do not forget to first condition.

@z100 Yeah I just realized that too :D I arrived at $x=\tan{x}$, which from a quick wolframalpha check only has numerical solutions it seems.

The slope of $kx$ is $k$ so one wants to find the $x$ where the slope of $\sin x$ is also $k$
and where both curves meet, i.e., $kx = \sin x$ and $(d/dx)\sin x=k = \cos x$. This leads
to $x=\tan x$ which has the numerical solutions 0 and 4.493409, $k=-0.217233\ldots$, more digits in https://oeis.org/A115365 and https://oeis.org/A213053 .
